# How to make my user's blogs visible in search engines?

Tags: html, search-engine, visual-web-developer

In my web site my users can create their own blog.
When user create the blog, all the blog content saved in database and it load the content from db when some one request for it.

My question is that these blogs are searchable in search engines like google?

If not how i make it searchable or what are the ways which i can optimize the discoverableness in search engines?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The short answer is "you probably don't need to do anything".  If a search engine crawls your site, it can retrieve - and index - whatever data your links generate.  LONGER ANSWER: you might want to consider using Wordpress, if you're not already doing so.  Wordpress offers many different advantages - including many (free!) plugins for [SEO.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your pages are rendered server side, your articles will be crawled by the bots and indexed in search engines. It's about time.

However, you can increase your chances to be indexed faster and better with these simple techniques:

- Add enough correct meta tags in your html head [Meta tags](https://moz.com/blog/seo-meta-tags)
- Add a robots.txt file in the root of your site [Robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/)
- Add a sitemap file in the root of your site [Sitemap](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/)
- Add json-ld description of your blog and each article in the head of your pages [Json-ld](https://json-ld.org/)
- Be sure to use semantic html for your content [Semantic HTML](https://www.inboundnow.com/html5-semantic-elements-mean-seo/)
- Provide social links and social pages that point links to your site

Those are basic, yet effective ways to assure your site to be properly indexed in search engines.

You can also test your SEO eanking with online tools like this one [rankgen.com](http://rankgen.com)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try these techniques